# No service of type Factory available in ProjectScopeServices Build Essue

Tags: android

i just updated my Android Studio version 2.1.1 to 2.2 and because of that my project can't be Build.
It shows me that Eroor :

"Gradle sync failed: No service of type Factory available in ProjectScopeServices"

Error:No service of type Factory available in ProjectScopeServices.